# How to delete image from firebase storage react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-firebase

I want to delete an image uploaded to firebase storage when the user deletes their account. I read the docs and tried what they specify but it doesnt work. i get back an `error  error Error: No object exists at the desired reference.`

the console.log shows

`{path: "/users/w3jvGrcMJ7TSUguQRRvRa8eHEIF3/undefined", _storage: Storage}path: "/users/w3jvGrcMJ7TSUguQRRvRa8eHEIF3/undefined"_storage: Storage {_app: App, _customUrlOrRegion: undefined, namespace: "storage"}fullPath: (...)key: (...)put: (...)__proto__: ReferenceBase "ref"`

deleteaccount.js

```
try{
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let uid = user.uid;
let ref = firebase.storage().ref(`/users/${uid}/`).child()
    console.log(ref,'ref')  
await ref.delete()

} catch(e){

console.log(e)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's seems correct, can you try something like this ?

```
// Create a reference to the file to delete
var desertRef = firebase.storage().child('images/example.jpg');

// Delete the file
desertRef.delete().then(function() {
  // File deleted successfully
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

Comment: the image uploaded has a custom file name like 34235-3423423-34324df so how can i reference that file name?

Comment: @obumoon- you can use the key name to delete

Answer (score 3):

```
let imageRef = storage.refFromURL(URL);
imageRef.delete()
```